# How to "plant" bloomberg function BDP into cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I have the following problem, 
Say I have the following cell (very simplified):
`CBA 4.5 01/22/2019`, I want to use VBA to plant a `BDP()` function in the adjacent cell in order to find out what the ISIN is. Without excel I would use `=BDP(A1 & " Corp"; "ID_ISIN")`right?

I am attempting to insert this function in VBA, and it does not work:

`TOMS.Cells(1, 2).Value.Formula = "=BDP(" & TOMS.Cells(1, 1).Value & " Corp, ID_ISIN)"`

Any ideas?

Comment: ';' vs ',' in the two versions? and parentheseis on ID_ISIN

Comment: Remove the .Value for starters. TOMS.Cells(1, 2).Formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `"` inside the formula, which must be doubled in vba:

```
 TOMS.Cells(1, 2).Formula = "=BDP(""" & TOMS.Cells(1, 1).Value & " Corp"", ""ID_ISIN"")"
```

Comment: What is mean TOMS in TOMS.Cells(1, 2) ? Thank you !

Comment: It is a worksheet variable.  It refers to an actual worksheet.

Comment: maybe.  It may be the sheet codename or it may be a variable like `Dim TOMS as Worksheet` and `Set TOMS =worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Do you know please, how to get all the Code Isin (for example 500 codes for SP 500) ? Do I need to use the function For/Next ? Thank you !

Comment: You will need to ask a new question showing what you have tried.